# Mongock and @Value annotation does not appear to work

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I am trying to use the @Value annotation to grab the URI and database name while creating a SpringBootMongock object via SpringBootMongockBuilder and during mvn install it attempts to load the application context and fails because my Spring Contract tests cannot connect to the database in my application.yml file. Which I do not want while building my app anyways. 
I have gotten around this by injecting the Environment object in my method signature but I don't understand why  the @Value is not working. I have annotated the class with @Configuration which works fine.

Update: I still need to grab the URI from the yaml file to create my MongoClient using the @Bean annotation..

```
    @Configuration
    public class MongockConfiguration {

    @Value(${spring.data.mongodb.uri})
    private String uri;

   @Bean
   public MongoClient mongoClient(){
      return MongoClients.create(uri);
   }

   @Bean
   public SpringBootMongock mongock(Application context, Environment environment)   throws Exception {

   return new SpringBootMongockBuilder(mongoClient(), dbname, ChangeLogOne.class.getPackage().getName()).setEnabled(migrate).setApplicationContext(applicationContext).build();
}
```

some of the above values I pull from the Environment object as the @Value wasn't working for me .. no need to provide exact values here

exception is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongock' defined in class path resource [blah/dht/mcs/registrationservice/config/MongockConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.SpringBootMongock]: Factory method 'mongock' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='testUser', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.SpringBootMongock]: Factory method 'mongock' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='testUser', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='testUser', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed.", "code" : 18, "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed" }
```

and for the record with the values hardcoded vs using the @Value annotation everything works as expected.

Comment: Could you please share the code that you are working with and the stacktrace of the error you are receiving for furthur analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not related to Mongock, but I see pretty clear that is due to MongoClient not being injected whenever you get the error.

As you mentioned it works when you provide the uri hardcoded, I was tempted to say that Spring doesn't find the `spring.data.mongodb.uri`, but if I am not wrong, it would fail saying that property is not found, rather than the error you are getting, as you are not providing a default value.

Anyway, it's something around there, for some reason, whenever you are running this and fails, the MongoClient is not added to the context for some reason.

I hope you find it useful.

Comment: My issue was that I did not do a class level MockBean of MongockConfiguration.class in my SpringBootTest which was testing our spring contracts. Thanks again for your assistance.